# SQL+Fetch rows with latest date+Case when row_number()+Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, impala

I have a table with fields(id, date, product) with below sample data

```
id  date    Product current_Flag    Expected_flag
14834   2019-01-03 00:00:00 A   1   1
14834   2019-01-31 00:00:00 B   0   0
14834   2019-02-28 00:00:00 C   0   0
14834   2019-03-30 00:00:00 C   0   0
14834   2019-01-03 00:00:00 D   0   1
```

I'm trying the `case when row_number() over (partition by id order by date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as flag`,
But for a particular distinct Id with min date, it is getting flag as 1, but I need to flag as for a particular Id & min date and product as 1 flag as shown in Expected_flag

```
case when row_number() over (partition by id order by date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as flag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `dense_rank()` instead :

```
case when dense_rank() over (partition by id order by date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Expected_flag
```